# Non-linear system of 3 equations with 3 unknowns - Python

Tags: python, nonlinear-equation

I'm doing a project of Off-Shore Wind Energy where I am designing a turbine.
This includes to define some of the features of the turbine.

I need to solve a system of **3 non linear equations** with **3 variables**.

#### 3 equations to solve

[image: 3 equations to solve]

The 3 variables (unknowns) are:

- `a`
- `ai`
- `Bi`

The other values are given.

#### Attempts to solve

I already tried using `fsolve`, `sym.nonlinsolve`, and a couple more and I can't figure it out.

On my last attempt I substituted Bi from the first 2 equations with the 3rd equation. I add my minimal reproducible example by substituting the values I already know with the actual numbers:

```py
def prueba(q):
    x = q[0]
    y = q[1]
    

    f1 = ((2.118182068620592)*(math.degrees(math.cos(math.degrees(math.atan((1-x)/((10.0)*(1+y)))))))*((1)+((0.016313)*(math.degrees(math.tan(math.degrees(math.atan((1-x)/((10.0)*(1+y)))))))))-((x)/(1-x))
    f2 = ((2.118182068620592)/((8)*(math.pi)*(16.609991369048576)*(math.degrees(math.cos(math.degrees(math.atan((1-x)/((10.0)*(1+y))))))))*((1)-((0.016313)*(math.degrees(mpmath.cot(math.degrees(math.atan((1-x)/((10.0)*(1+y)))))))))-((y)/(1+y))
    
    
    return np.array([f1,f2])

guessArray = [0.3329,0.00373] 

answer = fsolve(prueba,guessArray)
x = answer[0]
y = answer[1]
print(x,y)
```

If someone knows how to solve this I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please format your code appropriately so it can be more easily read. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting explains how quite nicely.

Comment: Oscar, have a look at the __formatting and markdown__ of your question. I edited to give you an example (learning purpose) and to attract answers ️

Comment: Can you **explain the equations**, their purpose (which turbine features) and mathematical terms (like `Zc Cl` or `8 pi kr`) !? – in human language  Although you claim attempts using `fsolve` etc. I miss them in your [example] Please add to your question!

Comment: sure, I'm new to the plattform so sorry for any format mistakes:

- The first equation of the image is for the axial induction factor (how much the wind speed (in axial direction) decreases because of the presence of the turbine). In this equation "a" represents the axial induction factor.

- The second equation is the rotational induction factor (same thing but for the rotational speed). "a1" represents rotational induction factor.

The other terms are values that I already calculated:
Z: number of blades
c: chord of the airfoil (length of the profile of the blade)
CONTINUE NEXT COMM

Comment: Cl: lift coefficient (how much lift force the turbine has according to it's geometry)
k: Prandtl factor
f: load funtion

And the 3rd equation Betai is the angle between rotational speed and relative speed (combination of axial wind speed, rotational speed and the induction factors)....and Betai relates both induction factors so it should help us to solve the equation

Comment: I updated the code with the minimal reproducible example (attempt)... Thank you!!! :)